# C#, How to get current desktop wallpaper in win7 and win10 by using same codes?

Tags: c#, windows

If I set a picture as desktop wallpaper and then delete this picture. How can I get current desktop wallpaper image file?
I know registry key "*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper*" stored a path. But different between win7 and win10.

- In win7, the value of key "WallPaper" is always "*C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg*"
- In win10, the value of key "WallPaper" is the path of the picture (like "*C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\1.jpg*"). **When I delete this file, I can not find it through this path.**

So, I can not read the registry key to get wallpaper path, It is useless in win10. Anyone has some solutions?

Comment: No expert here, but maybe this related article could be of help: https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-screwing-up-your-gorgeous-w-1788901567

Answer (score 0):

When you set an image as your desktop background, it will be converted to match your screen and position preferences like fill, zoom, fit etc. The path to the source image is written in a binary value named TranscodedImageCache at the following Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
```

The path to the source image as a binary value in the Registry.

To extract the path of the image from the TranscodedImageCache value, you need to run this script:

```html
Const HKCU = &H80000001 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER

sComputer = "."   

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
            & sComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

sKeyPath = "Control Panel\Desktop\"
sValueName = "TranscodedImageCache"
oReg.GetBinaryValue HKCU, sKeyPath, sValueName, sValue


sContents = ""

For i = 24 To UBound(sValue)
  vByte = sValue(i)
  If vByte <> 0 And vByte <> "" Then
    sContents = sContents & Chr(vByte)
  End If
Next

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "explorer.exe /select,""" & sContents & """"
```

You can paste this text into Notepad and then save it as a VBS file

Comment: It is usless in this condition: I set a picture as wallpaper, and delete this picture. Then I run the VBS file, but it can not find wallpaper file, because I have deleted it.